# Discrete Fourier Transform Unexpected Peak

Tags: python, numpy, dft

I am implementing a DFT and transformed a sine wave (f = 440 Hz) as test. However there is a peak in the transformed signal where I don't expect one (see figure below). 
Can someone see why it is there?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = 0.1
freq = 440
Fs = 2000
T = 1/Fs
N = int(Fs * t)

# signal information                 
omega = 2 * np.pi * freq       # angular frequency of the sine wave
t_vec = np.arange(N) * T     # time vector for plotting
y = np.sin(omega * t_vec)  # sine input signal

def DFT(y, N):
    dft = []
    angle = (-1 * 1j * 2 * np.pi) / (N)
    for k in range(int(N)):
        X = 0
        for n in range(int(N)):
            X += y[n] * np.exp(angle * k * n)
        dft.append(X)
    return dft

freq_vec = Fs * np.arange((N))/N

dft_signal = np.abs(DFT(y = y, N = N))

#Plots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
ax1.plot(t_vec, y, label='$y = numbers')
ax1.set(ylabel='Amplitude', xlabel='Time [s]', title = 'Input Signal')
ax2.plot(freq_vec, dft_signal, linewidth=5)
ax2.set(yscale='log', xscale='log', ylabel='Amplitude', xlabel='Frequency [Hz]', title = 'DFT of Input Signal')
plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems good to me. What you see are simply the negative frequencies since the Fourier Transform of a sine function is made of a peak in the positive frequencies and one peak in the negative. Don't plot it in xlog scale and it will appear more obvious! Then it is just a matter of `fftshift` to put the zero frequency in the middle or at the beginning of the array (like your implementation).

Remember that if your frequency range is `Fs` your DFT only goes from `-Fs/2` to `+Fs/2`